# What's the shortest way to find a dict in a list?

Tags: javascript, python, list

```py
[o for o in a if o['k'] == v][0]
```

This miserable line of code requires 3 references to the dict `o`.  Compare the JavaScript version, with not a single direct reference to `o`:

```js
a.find(({ k }) => k == v)
```

It not only requires fewer references, it uses fewer characters without broaching unreadable code-golf territory.

Is there a shorter way to find a dict in a list in Python comparable to this?

Perhaps Python doesn't even have an equivalent to JavaScript's `Array.prototype.find`.  The first line of code seems to be more equivalent to `Array.prototype.filter`.

Comment: Check with panda's dataframes

Comment: *No single direct reference to `o`* but it does have reference to `k`, doesn't it ?

Comment: Personally, I have no idea what the JS code is saying, but it's been years since I've programmed in that language.   For the Python, you probably want to use `next(....)` rather than `[....][0]` since you're just trying to find the first element that satisfies the property.  

I'm not sure why the number of references to the variable bothers you so much.

Comment: can you share an example of `a` and explain what are you looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* write it like this instead:

```py
result = next(filter(lambda o: o['k'] == v, a))
```

It's not exactly shorter, but it is in some ways less repetitive.

Documentation for `next` and `filter` is on [this page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html); you can find a tutorial on `lambda` functions [here](https://realpython.com/python-lambda/).

Even if you decide to stick with the comprehension-style syntax, by the way, you should probably refactor your code into a [generator expression](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/#building-generators-with-generator-expressions) rather than a list comprehension, since there is no need to build the list in memory if you only need one item from it:

```py
result = next(o for o in a if o['k'] == v)
```